# Помощь по коду мультивалютности

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Всем привет.

Подскажите пожалуйста.

Есть к примеру код

```html
<div id="lang_sel_click" class="lang_sel_click">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="?aelia_cs_currency=RUB" class="lang_sel_sel icl-en">RUB (₽)</a>
            <ul style="visibility: hidden;">
                <li class="icl-fr"><a rel="alternate" href="?aelia_cs_currency=USD"><span class="icl_lang_sel_native">USD ($)</span></a></li>
                <li class="icl-de"><a rel="alternate" href="?aelia_cs_currency=EUR"><span class="icl_lang_sel_native">EUR (€)</span></a></li>
                <li class="icl-de"><a rel="alternate" href="?aelia_cs_currency=RUB"><span class="icl_lang_sel_native">RUB (₽)</span></a></li>
                <li class="icl-de"><a rel="alternate" href="?aelia_cs_currency=UAH"><span class="icl_lang_sel_native">UAH (₴)</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Как сделать так что бы при выборе к примеру `USD` вверху фиксировался `USD`, а если `RUB` или другую то другая фиксировалась вверху.

Очень нужна помощь

Comment: Как вариант сохранять выбранную валюту в куки. При открытии страницы проверять значение

Comment: Вариант неплохой но мало вероятно что подойдет. Есть определение валюты по региону и если пользщователь заходит из США то задействуется валюта USD и в идеале ее уже сразу отобразить вверху.